# How to pass multiple params in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

In my batch file I want to pass multiple parameters to some other application.

Now I do it

```
app.exe %1 %2
```

and it can only pass two parameters, but I want to pass all the parameters that are passed to the batch(I would rather not write *%1 %2 %3 %4 ...*)

Is there any magic way to do it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There is a magic way! I knew it, but I could not remember it.

its `%*`

Comment: How and where do you use `%*`?

Comment: thanks! I used before `command %1 %2 ~~ %9`. Now using `command %*`.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [SHIFT](http://ss64.com/nt/shift.html) prompt and loop through the arguments. Here is a demonstrative example where you would replace the final ECHO prompt with a prompt to load your application.

```
@ECHO OFF

SET PARAMS=

:_PARAMS_LOOP

REM There is a trailing space in the next line; it is there for formatting.
SET PARAMS=%PARAMS%%1 
ECHO %1
SHIFT

IF NOT "%1"=="" GOTO _PARAMS_LOOP

ECHO %PARAMS%

PAUSE
```

This may be useful if you need some sort of dynamic parameter counting, or if you want to disallow a certain parameter.

Comment: +1, only I would place the empty parameter check *before* processing the parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use one double quoted parameter. When calling the other application, you just use the `%~N` device on the command line to remove the quotes.

If some parameters you intend to pass to the application are themselves double-quoted, those quote chars must be repeated twice.

Here's an illustration script that uses the first parameter as the application's name and the second as a combined parameter list to pass to the application:

```
@ECHO OFF
CALL %1 %~2
```

Here are examples of calling the script for different cases (pass one parameter or several parameters or quoted parameters).

1. Pass 1 parameter to the app:

   ```
   C:\>mybatch.bat app.exe "app_param"
   C:\>mybatch.bat app.exe app_param
   ```
2. Pass several parameters:

   ```
   C:\>mybatch.bat app.exe "app_param1 app_param2 app_param3"
   ```
3. Pass a parameter that includes spaces (and so must be quoted):

   ```
   C:\>mybatch.bat app.exe """parameter with spaces"""
   ```
4. A combined example: some parameters are with spaces, others aren't:

   ```
   C:\>mybatch.bat app.exe "param_with_no_spaces ""parameter with spaces"" another_spaceless_param"
   ```