# How to Pass Argument When Run Executible Into Input In That Executible?

Tags: windows, cmd, exe

So, I have an executible which I run in cmd with one argument. When I run it, that program will ask for input many times. I want to write all the input in argument so I will not constantly press enter every input. How to do it?

For Example, my program name is program.exe with one argument and after I run it, it will ask me to input 'y' or 'n', so I only need to type:

`program.exe <argument> y`

then press enter to run it. Can I? If I can't, how to do it similarly?

P.S. Source code of the program is C script and for input it's using `scanf`. I can't change the source code.

Comment: would that help ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871620/how-to-pass-multiple-params-in-batch

Comment: @A.Joly It didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your inputs into a file, say `inputs.txt` and then you can run it this way `program.exe<inputs.txt`.

Note that you should separate inputs with a blank space or newline.
Also, the inputs passed here are not the same as the inputs your will get with the argument vector variable (char** argv). These inputs are rather passed on calls to the console input, be it scanf or cin(in case it's c++)

Comment: If there are real argument in my program, should I put it in that text file or write it as argument?

Comment: arguments are all the values you type on the command line before running the application so `program.exe y something` has 3 arguments