# How to use multiple params in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file, parameters

I tried a lot (e.g. [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4871620/how-to-pass-multiple-params-in-batch) and other posts), but nothing works for me.

I'm parsing a file to get several results (e.g. get_AC-NAME.bat):

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=\,]" %%i in ('findstr Sessions\ _conf\WinSCP.ini') do @echo %%i
```

I'd like to use each single result as variable to pass to an other batch-file (e.g. get_log.bat):

```
@echo off
cls

if "%~1" == "" goto ERROR

::set Parameter
set LOGPATH=PATH_TO\WinSCP.log
set AC-LOGS-DIR=PATH_TO\AC-Logs
set WINSCP-DIR=PATH_TO\_tools\
set NOW=%DATE:~-4%-%DATE:~3,2%-%DATE:~0,2%_%TIME:~0,2%%TIME:~3,2%%TIME:~6,2%

md %AC-LOGS-DIR%\%NOW%

:MENU
set AC-NAME=%1

"%WINSCP-DIR%\WinSCP.com" ^
  /log=%LOGPATH% /ini=%AC-LOGS-DIR%\_conf\WinSCP.ini ^
  /command ^
    "open %AC-NAME% -hostkey=*" ^
    "call tar cvzf /data/%AC-NAME%.tgz /var/log/app-log*" ^
    "get "/data/%AC-NAME%.tgz" "%AC-LOGS-DIR%\%NOW%\"" ^
    "rm /data/%AC-NAME%.tgz" ^
    "exit"

timeout /T 5 /NOBREAK

set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
if %WINSCP_RESULT% equ 0 (
  echo Success
) else (
  echo Error
)
exit /b %WINSCP_RESULT%

:ERROR
echo Use the rigt way: %0 AC-NAME
```

What do I have to do? How can I combine both batches? I don't get it.

Thanks for your help.

- Update:
  At first I tried to build a dynamic menu based on the results for the findstr - not that easy. Now I'm fine with the second target to use "get_log.bat %1", but if it's possible I would be happy with my first target.

Comment: `timeout` resets `%errorlevel%`, so you should `set WINSCP_RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%` *before* the `timeout`. In your first batch file (the one-liner) change to `... ) do call get_log.bat "%%I"`

Comment: Hi Stephan, I'll try your suggestion. I changed back from `timeout` to `ping 127.0.0.1 -n 5>nul` - not nice, but working fine for me.

Comment: `ping` also (re)sets `%errorlevel%`, so this doesn't help...

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Hint: There is a colon after `an other batch-file` followed by some code.

Comment: Hi @MartinPrikryl , I'd lile to use the result from get_AC-NAME.bat (multiple lines) to run the file get_log.bat with each parameters. I would go for only one single batch call, too. But until now I have no idea how to get this (parse the file WinSCP.ini to find the seach string and use every single result to do the rest from get_log.bat.)

Comment: @Stephan : Damn.

Comment: Stephan already hinted how to solve that in the very first comment: `do call get_log.bat "%%I"`